# how to return number of distinct values django

Tags: python, mysql, django, group-by

i'm working on project for a hotel

```
family = 'family'
single = 'single'

room_types = (
    (family , 'family'),
    (single , 'single'),
)
class Room(models.Model):
    room_no = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    beds = models.IntegerField(default=2)
    balcon = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    room_type = models.CharField(max_length=15,choices=room_types,default=single)
```

this is my views(query)

```
lists = Room.objects.order_by().values('balcon ','beds','room_type').distinct().annotate(total=Count('beds',distinct=True)+Count('balcon',distinct=True)+Count('room_type',distinct=True))
```

i expect the query to return something like this `beds: 4 , balcon : True , room_type : single , total : 10` `beds: 3 , balcon : True , room_type : family, total : 4` and so on
but it doesnt return as i expected ! is it possible to make a group by based on several fields and count based on that selected fields please ?
thank you for helping ..

Comment: It is not really clear to me *what* youaim to do. Exactly what do you count? If there are two `room_type`s, and one has a `balcon`  and another hans't, then what should the result be?

Comment: in this case : two `room_type` both are `family` but one of them has `balcon` and the other dont have , i expect to return ( family , True : quantity:1 room) ( family , False: quantity:1 room)

Comment: i want to return quantity ( number of rooms with unique features)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem is it possible please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Room.objects.values('room_type', 'beds', 'balcon').annotate(
    total=Count('pk')
).order_by('room_type', 'beds', 'balcon')
```

This will provide a queryset of dictionaries that look like:

```
<QuerySet [
    {'room_type' : 'family', 'beds': 3 , 'balcon' : True , 'total' : 4},
    {'room_type' : 'single', 'beds': 4 , 'balcon' : True, 'total' : 10}
]>
```

for each combination of unique values, it will thus add an extra element to the dictionary named `'total'` that contains the number of rooms for that category.

Comment: thank you , but it return wrong number `total`

Comment: @HunarMohammed: aaarrggghhh... I made a mistake, it is `Count('pk')`, not `Sum('pk')`, otherwise we are summing up the primary keys.

Comment: yes , thank you so much , i was expected to you to answer it , and i happened , you did , thank you  again

Comment: sorry , i have one more question i have another field in the Room model named `status:boolean field` can i return something like this `'room_type' : 'single', 'beds': 4 , 'balcon' : True, 'total' : 10 , True status : 6 ,False status:4` i want to return number of available rooms in that query , without changing the `group by` to show how many rooms are taken in that category

Comment: @HunarMohammed: exactly where does the `True` and `False` status come from? The room, nor another object seems to store if a room is taken or not. There does not seem to be anything in the model to determine that. I would also suggest to ask a new question, this makes it easier for people to search for a question and get the corresponding answer.

Comment: we have some rooms which gives for about 1 month the entire month (day + night) times  will be take , the admin edit that Room to `status=False` , thank you for your suggestion , i will try it